# center a block with css using natural width of first line

Tags: css

I have text that I would like to display like this:

```
SOME HEADING TEXT
And then a bunch
of text under
that wrapped to
the width of the
heading.
```

What I mean is, I want a heading with some body text underneath. I want the text left-justified within this block. I want the width of the block to be defined by the width of the heading. Then I want the whole block centered within its parent.

If I knew that the heading was, say, 100 pixels, I could write:

```
<div style="width: 100px;margin:0 auto">
etc.
```

But I don't know the width of the heading. Even if it was static and I measured it, I would think this would be unreliable on different browsers, if the user changes his font size, etc.

I tried saying width:0 and putting &nbsp's into the heading. The heading displayed fine but the body text displayed with one word per line.

Any helpful hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do by absolutely positioning the text within the containing header element.

HTML:

```
<h1>
    SOME HEADING TEXT

    <span>
        And then a bunch
        of text under
        that wrapped to
        the width of the
        heading.
    </span>

</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 { display: inline-block; position: relative; }
h1 span { text-align: center; display: block; position: absolute; font: 14px/20px Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ftkdD/1/

**Note: I've only tested this in Firefox. Also, it's important to note that the element height may become an issue if there is content set below the element as to clear the height, you'll need to apply bottom margin or padding since the absolute positioned text won't have any bearing on the elements overall height. As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ftkdD/2/ **

Comment: Hmm, this is tantalizing but not quite there. The combination of display modes does indeed make the body text wrap under the heading. But I wanted to center the whole block within a parent, and using these display modes I was not able to make it center. I don't quite understand why this works the way it does anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fiddle look like what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/2Rc2j/3/

CSS:

```
#main{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}

#header{
    background: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="main">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that assumes that I know that the width I want is 200 pixels, and the trick for me is that I don't know the width. I want it to be the width of whatever text is pulled out of a database record.

Comment: @Jay You can easily use jQuery or javascript to set the width of the element once you retrieve it from the database

Comment: @Jay Furthermore, you could use your server side language to build the element with an inline width style.

Comment: RE using JS: Interesting. Seems messy,  to have to do half the layout in with CSS and half with JS, but I guess it's better than not being able to do it at all.

Comment: RE calculating width server side: I don't know how I could do that. I don't know any features in ASP (in this case) to calculate what the displayed width of a string will be in the browser. I'd think that would be impossible, as I don't necessarily even know what font it will use. I could estimate, of course, find what the width would be if displayed with some random font on the server or just count the number of characters and multiply by some average number.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays we can do something like this:

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    <h1>SOME HEADING TEXT</h1>
    And then a bunch of text under that wrapped to the width of the heading.
    </body>
```

**CSS**:

```
h1 {
    width: max-content; } /* Natural width without wrapping. */
body {
    margin: 0 auto; /* Centered left and right. */
    width: min-content; } /* Squeezed to the minimum. */
```

**Result**:

```
· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ·
·       SOME HEADING TEXT       ·
·                               ·
·       And then a bunch        ·
·       of text under           ·
·       that wrapped to         ·
·       the width of the        ·
·       heading.                ·
·                               ·
·                               ·
· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ·
```

*See: [CSS box sizing values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing/#sizing-values), [`min-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content) and [`max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content).*